# Debug COM port read/write using software/virtual COM port and console/terminal on the other end

Tags: delphi, debugging, serial-port, virtual-serial-port

I have a Delphi application that reads/writes to a COM port connected to a large hardware device, so I don't usually have the hardware available during development.  That said, the communication protocol is fairly simple, so I can generally do the development and have someone onsite test it, and it usually works.  Occasionally I run into a harder problem, though.  To solve this, I'd like to setup a virtual COM port where one side of the COM port is my application and the other side is a very simple COM port debug console (similar to the old modem terminal programs), where ASCII commands my app sends are logged onscreen and I can type in some ASCII command to send back to my application to simulate the hardware device.  I've been unable to find any tools that provide a virtual/software COM port and a console/terminal to debug with.  Does anyone have software suggestions and steps to set something like this up?

The software/virtual COM port and terminal need to support Windows 7 64-bit (or Vista 32 if necessary).

Comment: You don't have a second COM port you can just connect the first one to?

Comment: Unfortunately, my development PCs don't have any serial ports, so I'd prefer a software-only solution, if available.  If not, I could consider adding a serial card to the desktop PC.  A software solution would be preferred because it would work anywhere (on a laptop, without a cable or serial-card handy, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [Advanced Virtual COM Port](http://kernelpro.com/index.html) and I'm quite happy with it. Not free, but works like a charm - even with Win7-x64.

Comment: I ended up using this tool.  It has a free 64-bit trial, works good, and was easy to install and configure, compared to com0com (which requires modifying your 64-bit machine to allow unsigned drivers).  I used [232ANALYZER](http://www.commfront.com/CommFront-Downloads.htm) as the COM port debugging console/terminal, but I didn't find that program as reliable or well-designed, so there are likely better options out there for a debugging terminal.

Answer (score 5):

I'm doing something similar with paired virtual COM ports created by
http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I'm using that one too. Works like a charm. I usually create 2 applications. 1 hardware device emulator, and one application to control it. With com0com I can run and debug everything on 1 pc. By emulating the hardware device, I can test all sort of edge-cases that would be difficult to mimic with the real device.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just insert a redirector at the lowest level of your application which will pop up a console instead of writing data to COM? Should not take long.

Answer (score 0):

I can't vouch for it, but sounds like something like this is what you're looking for. http://www.windows7download.com/win7-free-virtual-serial-ports-emulator/yarqmowu.html

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Eterlogic's Virtual Serial Ports Emulator](http://www.eterlogic.com/Products.VSPE.html) successfully for exactly this on a laptop with no serial ports. It's a bit easier to set up than Com0Com, which I have also used. It's also useful for serial port spying if you need to reverse engineer any communications
The 32-bit version is free, the 64-bit version is currently $25.  Try it out on Vista32 to see if it does what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Com0Com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/) for this purpose, but I don't know whether it works with anything more recent than Windows XP.